# What are some of the uses of maxDepth for a binary search tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have been thinking about what some of the reasons for finding the maximum depth of a binary search tree are, and also what the best uses of the function would be.

So far, a reason I have thought of for implementing it is to maintain the data structure's efficiency. If the maximum depth path became considerably longer than the other possible paths, especially compared to the minimum depth path, there may be a much more noticeable hit on performance when traversing through that path, especially considering that a recursive call uses a good amount of memory.

What other reasons are there for a maximum depth function? Thanks in advance for reading my question and responding.

Answer (score 2):

This is like asking how addition can be used in real life...

This really depends on the problem that the maxDepth operation is applied to. For instance, the max depth might be worthwhile for estimating the maximum number of elements that can exist inside of the tree. This might be a quick shortcut for allocating memory.
In a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), finding the maxDepth would give you the length of longest word. If the tree represent your ancestral tree, finding maxDepth would give you the total number of ancestors. This list goes on and on...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If a binary search tree has nodes that only hold integer values, could maxDepth tell anything about the last node on the longest path (other than that it is farthest from the root node)?